# Active Record: delete_all with limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Trying to get a definitive answer on whether it's possible to limit a `delete_all` to X number of records.

I'm trying the following:

```
Model.where(:account_id => account).order(:id).limit(1000).delete_all
```

but it doesn't seem to respect the `limit` and instead just deletes all Model where `:account_id => account`.

I would expect it to generate the following:

```
delete from model where account_id = ? order by id limit 1000
```

This seems to work fine when using `destroy_all` but I want to delete in bulk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.send(:delete_sql,'delete from table where account_id = <account_id> limit 1000')
```

You have to use send because 'delete_sql' is protected, but this works.

I found that removing the 'order by' significantly sped it up too.

I do think it's weird that using `.limit` works with `destroy_all` but not `delete_all`

Comment: It's worth to mention that removing ORDER BY can also cause random problems, specially if your DB cluster works under a replication mechanism.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
Model.delete(Model.where(:account_id => account).order(:id).limit(1000).pluck(:id))
```

Comment: Can I ask what kind of query you're expecting there?

Something like: `delete from model where id in (id1, id2, id3)`?

Comment: Yep `DELETE FROM "models" WHERE "models"."id" IN (1, 2)`

Comment: Note that this will take two queries for what would otherwise take 1

Answer (score 4):

This one also worked pretty well to me (and my needs)

```
Model.connection.exec_delete('DELETE FROM models ORDER BY id LIMIT 10000', 'DELETE', [])
```

I know it might seem a bit cumbersome but it'll return the affected rows AND also will **log the query through the rails logger**. ;)

Answer (score 2):

This was the best solution I used to delete millions of rows:

```
sql = %{ DELETE FROM model WHERE where_clause LIMIT 1000 }

results = 1
while results > 0 do
  results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_delete(sql)
end
```

This performed much faster than deleting in batches where the IDs were being used in the SQL.

Answer (score -2):

Or `Model.where(:account_id => account).order(:id).limit(1000).map(&:delete)`, although it is not the best approach if you have thousands of records to delete/destroy.

`Model.delete_all()` seems to be the best option as it delegates to SQL the task of selecting the records and mass delete them.

Comment: But that will run 1000 SQL queries

Comment: Agreed with Alex. Want to run as few queries as possible. Need to do this a whole thing a 36,000 times because I've got 36M records to delete.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the resulting query on both approaches. Alex's answer is a lot better as it delegates everything to SQL.